# Find the set of values of x for which $\lvert \frac {x-1}{x+1} \rvert <2 $

Tags: inequality

How to solve this inequality question involving modulus?

I can’t get the same answer as the book [answer below]

I know the properties of absolute values, that is

If $\lvert x \rvert <k$ , then $-k < x < k$.

So for this question, this is my working:

$-2<\lvert \frac {x-1}{x+1} \rvert <2 $

When $-2<\lvert \frac {x-1}{x+1} \rvert $

$-2x-2 < x-1$

$-1<3x$

$x>- \frac {1}{3}$

And when $\lvert \frac {x-1}{x+1} \rvert <2 $

$x-1<2x+2$

$x>-3$

So, I got $x> - \frac {1}{3}\:$ or $\:x>-3$

However,  The **answer given is  $\{ {x\mid x<-3\: \text{ or }\: x> -\frac {1}{3}, ∈ℝ} \}$  **

I don't think the answer from the book is wrong, since the following graph confirms that the book answer is correct.

Please show me how to get the answer.

Thank you
[image]

Comment: $-2<|\frac{x-1}{x+1}|$ always holds , if $x\ne -1$. You probably mean $-2<\frac{x-1}{x+1}$

Comment: Split the analysis into the cases $x <-1, x>1$ and $-1<x \leq 1$. You will get the answer easily.

Comment: Multiplying with $x+1$ changes the inequality-sign, if $x<-1$ holds.

Comment: @Peter why does the inequality sign change? And what does it mean for $ -2< \lvert \frac {x-1}{x+1} \rvert $ to always hold? Thanks

Comment: $(1)$ If you multiply an inequality with a negative number, the inequality-sign must be changed. Look at "x>1" which is equivalent to "-x<-1" $(2)$ The absolute value of any number is always non-negative, hence greater than $-2$

Comment: Got it, @Peter thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the analysis of the second part is that you have taken $|\frac{x-1}{x+1}| 
 = \frac{x-1}{x+1}$ and done the analysis. This is false : what about those $x$ for which we have $|\frac{x-1}{x+1}| = \boxed{-\frac{x-1}{x+1}}$?

---

You need to break your analysis according to *where* $|\frac{x-1}{x+1}| = \frac{x-1}{x+1}$ and where it is the negative of the expression. After this, you can work separately on each component.

---

For example, when is $\frac{x-1}{x+1} > 0$? It happens if and only if both numerator and denominator are positive, or both are negative. One checks that this comes to $x<-1$ or $x>1$.

In these intervals, one solves $-2<\frac{x-1}{x+1}<2$. (i.e. one solves this, then takes the intersection with $x<-1 \cup x>1$).

On the interval $-1 < x \leq 1$, one solves $-2 < -\frac{x-1}{x+1}< 2$. Then we can put them together to finish.

In short, your argument falls because you assumed that the value $\frac{x-1}{x+1}$ was positive all the time : instead you must break it into where it is negative, where it is positive and then work separately on both parts.

Comment: Okay i get it thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

The domain of validity of this inequation is $\mathbf R\smallsetminus\{-1\}$.

On this domain,
\begin{align} \biggl|\frac {x-1}{x+1}\biggr|<2  &\iff\biggl(\frac {x-1}{x+1}\biggr)^{\!2}<2^2
\iff \bigl(2(x+1)\bigr)^2-(x-1)^2>0\\[1ex]
&\iff (3x+1)(x+3)>0.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

If $x=a+ib$ where $a,b$ are real

We have $$\sqrt{(a-1)^2+b^2}<2\sqrt{(a+1)^2+b^2}$$

Squaring and simplifying we get 
$$b^2+a^2+\dfrac{10a}3+1>0$$

$$b^2+\left(a+\dfrac53\right)^2>\dfrac{25}9-1=\left(\dfrac43\right)^2$$

So, $x$ needs to lie outside the circle $$y^2+\left(x+\dfrac53\right)^2=\left(\dfrac43\right)^2$$

If $b=0,x=a$ is real

$$\left(a+\dfrac53\right)^2>\left(\dfrac43\right)^2\iff\left(a+\dfrac13\right)(a+3)>0$$

which happens

if $a>$max$\left(-\dfrac13,-3\right)$

or if $a<$min$\left(-\dfrac13,-3\right)$

In any case, $a\ne-1$